# New logarithms identity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$$\log_{x^{\frac{1}{n}}} x = \frac{\log_x x}{\log_x x^{\frac1 n}} = \frac{\log_x x}{\frac1 n} = n \log_x x = \log_xx^n$$

Hence, can we say that $\log_{x^{\frac{1}{n}}} x = \log_xx^n$, or is this identity not proven?

Comment: Notice that $n\log_x(x) = n$

Comment: And $\log_{x^{1/n}}x=n$ because $(x^{1/n})^n=x$.

Answer (score 1):

Using $\log_ax=\frac1{\log_xa}$, 
$$\log_{x^{(\frac1n)}}x=\frac1{\log_xx^{(\frac1n)}}=\frac1{\frac1n}=n$$ 
So this is just a manipulation, not an identity.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comments, we have
$$\log_{x^{\frac{1}{n}}} x=\frac{\log x}{\log x^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{\log x}{\frac1n\log x}=n\frac{\log x}{\log x}=n$$
Would I call this an identity? Probably not. Its more of a simplification. Study the proofs of some already existing log identities for some inspiration.